# SimpleForm & Bootstrap DateTimepicker for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need a date and time calender in form.
I found the gem [datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails) , Now i am trying to implement that like the below way, but it is not showing any error and also not working.

Step 1: i added the gem in Gemfile,
step 2: bundled install,
step 3: added the below line in application.css file like below,

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require_tree ./vendor/
```

step 4: added the line in application.js file like below ,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree ./vendor/
//= require_tree ./launchpad/
//= require_tree .
```

step 5: i generated a input files using following command:
  $ rails generate datetimepicker_rails:install
step 6: I changed the form like below:

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @task], html: {class: 'form-vertical', role: "form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :requested_pickup_dt, as: :datetime_picker %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

But it is not showing any error also not working.
please someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After your inputs are on the page you may need to actually call the `datetimepicker` function.

You could put this at the very bottom of your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
</script>
```

Or you could use the jQuery ready function to delay the init until the document is ready:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
});
```

You'll want to double check the generated source and make sure that your input has `datetimepicker` in the class attribute.

Comment: I have added $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        pickSeconds: false
    });

Comment: also i have datetimepicker class in my form input

Comment: <div class="input-append date datetimepicker"><input class="string datetime_picker optional" data-date-weekstart="0" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" data-language="en" id="task_requested_dropoff_dt" name="task[requested_dropoff_dt]" size="50" type="text"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" data-time-icon="icon-time"></i></span></div>

Comment: Your input has the class `datetime_picker`, not `datetimepicker`.  You could either change the class on the input, or adjust your JS to target `.datetime_picker`.

Comment: I used //= require bootstrap-datetimepicker in application.js . So it is not necessary to call datetimepicker function. I tested, it is working. but it shows only the date calender but not time calender. I think something problem with the gem file. Suggest me some better gem or plugin to do this.

Comment: Have you tried telling it explicitly to give you a time picker too, as shown in the docs?  http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/